# How can I change the interface of incoming call in ios that no jailbreak

Tags: ios

How to call the method of SpringBoard or CoreTelephony.framework without jailbreak....I want to develop a CRM(Customer Relationship Management) app that when someone calling user and he can be show the information about user's customer in calling view.

In a word...how can I show text in iPhone when the phone is ringing or calling....

BTW:↓

This app can show the incoming number's location when someone call you ,(Maybe,It's can de used in CN only..) ----->  http://dx4.wishdown.com:8088/soft/360MobileSafeEnterprise_1.0.3.zip?1061501409182x1381395280x1061548127328-935a63a79c690b6b6b268ad737c10c9c

Comment: I don't think it's possible without jailbreak.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the caller's photo in the address book using `ABPersonSetImageData`.
(That what I did in my app http://roysharon.com/CallAbout)